# How to properly describe events in Backbone views with JSdoc?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jsdoc

I am describing JavaScript code that uses the Backbone framework.
I am wondering how to document events that are declared in my views.

Let's say I have a class with this events:

```
define([], function(Backbone){
  let myView = Backbone.View.extend(
    model: myModel,
    initialize: function() {
        /**
         * @event                  <<- what should I specify here?
         */
        this.model.on('change:foo', function() {
          //do something
        }
    }

    events: {
      'click .btn-next': 'onClickNext',
      'click #finish': 'onClickFinish'
    },

    /**
     * @event                  <<- what should I specify here?
     */
    onClickNext: function() { 
      //do something
    },
    /**
     * @event                  <<- what should I specify here?
     */
    onClickFinish: function() {
       //do something
    }
  );
});
```

According to JSDoc documentation I should use something like:

```
/**
 * Description..
 * @event MyView#click
 * @listens MyView#click
 */
onClickNext(){}
```

But how to specify the class or id of an object that was clicked?
And what about event in the model? Should I use `@event myModel#change` or `@event myView#change`? And again: how to specify the property that should be changed?

Comment: I have answered your question, but this part of your question is unclear to me: "how to specify the property that should be changed?" If you clarify this, I will expand my answer.

Comment: You've unswered this part. I wanted to know how to specify the name of the model property, changing of which is triggering an event.

Answer (score 0):

If a method is the *listener* for an event emitted elsewhere, use `@listens`, **not** `@event`. The class in the `ClassName#eventName` notation is the class of the *emitter* of the event.

```js
    initialize: function() {
        /**
         * Anonymous event handler.
         *
         * @listens myModel#change:foo
         */
        this.model.on('change:foo', function() {
          //do something
        }
    }
```

If a method *triggers* an event that *other* methods might listen to, use `@fires`, **not** `@event`.

```js
    /**
     * Do what needs to be done when the user clicks #finish.
     *
     * @event myView#finish
     */
    onClickFinish: function() {
       //do something
       this.trigger('finish', this);
    }
```

Document *the event itself* using `@event`.

```js
       /**
        * Event reporting that the view is finished.
        *
        * @event myView#finish
        * @type {myView}
        */
       this.trigger('finish', this);
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I understand this. As I understand you, for my click events I should use: `@listens MyView#click:.btn-next`? Is that right? What about selecting button by its ID. `@listens MyView#click#finish` is not worked, because JSdoc parses finish as an event.

Comment: However, `@listens MyView:#finish#click` similar to what I expect. I am not sure is this way is correct or not.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. DOM events that a view listens for originate from its element, not the view itself, so that would be `@listens HTMLElement#click`. As far as I know, JSDoc does not support selector delegates in any way. `@listens MyView#finish` works, because this event is fired by the view rather than its element. Not sure about `#click#finish`; that might be doing something else than what you think.